# After modifing the source code of existing file system (such as ext2), how to rebuild and install it?

Tags: filesystems, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I am now learning the source code of ext2. I think the best way to understand it is to play with it, but I never built a Linux kernel before, so I was wondering if somebody could give me some detailed instructions on how to build the Linux kernel from the source code. I've created a VM with centos 6.8 as the compiling environment.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to figure out how the RHEL / CentOS kernel is built is actually to look at the source RPM's specfile. CentOS already has a wiki page on how to get the full kernel source, located at https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/I_need_the_Kernel_Source. Read section 2 of that page. Once you have the source RPM (SRPM) installed, the file `SPECS/kernel.spec` contains all the commands used to build the kernel binary package from source, including applying any relevant patches.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Let me follow the instructions on that webpage and try it out first. I'll let you know if I encounter any problems.